# geth --dev fails to mine more than one contract

Tags: go-ethereum

I installed geth and solc by following

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum-unstable
sudo apt-get install solc
```

then i ran

```
geth --dev
```

and did

```
geth attach
```

I created a contract and compiled it and "deployed" it to my blockchain.

```
var abi = <abi from solc>;
var jarContract = eth.contract(abi); 
var bin = '0x' + "<bytecode from solc>";
var txDeploy = {from:eth.accounts[0], data: bin, gas: 1000000}; 
var jar = jarContract.new(txDeploy);
```

It was instantly mined and I got an address for it and could work with it.

But then I did

```
var jar2 = jarContract.new(txDeploy);
```

i.e. using EXACTLY the same variables as before, and nothing ever happened. It was not "mined", I got no address and could not interact with the contract.

I am a bit stumped. I only seem to be able to get one contract out of --dev and then have to stop and start it again to "mine" another one.

Any thoughts would be welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me. Just tested.

Comment: Are you making sure to run more than 1 sealer nodes? If not, I think this issue could perhaps be due to the fact that running 1 sealer node will cause block generation issues (totally preventing it I believe)

Answer (score 0):

based on the [doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract), you shouldn't add '0x' before your byte code. The way to get the byte code of the contract is just:

```
let source = fs.readFileSync('nameContract.sol', 'utf8');
let compiledContract = solc.compile(source, 1);
let abi = compiledContract.contracts['nameContract'].interface;
let bytecode = compiledContract.contracts['nameContract'].bytecode;
```